# "Using" for object returned by function

Tags: .net, using, using-statement

I want use an SQLite connection for only a very short time.

Because I do this very often for different DBs, I wanted to create a function for that:

```
Public Function ConnectionFromPath(ByVal uDBPath As String) As SQLite.SQLiteConnection

    Dim nConn As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection
    With nConn
        .ConnectionString = "Data source=" & uDBPath
        .Open()
    End With

    Return nConn

End Function
```

Usually, I use "Using... End Using" for SQLite.SQLiteConnection

Now I simply say:

```
Using nCn As SQLite.SQLiteConnection = modDB.ConnectionFromPath(uDBPath)
    'Do something with it
End Using 'This should automatically close the db and free the file
```

Is it so easy, and my function "inherits" the "Using" from the SQLite.SQLiteConnection's "usability", or did I miss anything?

Comment: This is correct and I think you don't miss anything